# Not able to get input from the custom fragment dialog

Tags: android

i am displaying a custom dialog for user input on top of my list view activity layout. But when i try to refer the edit text in onCreateDialog() method, its always coming as blank. Below is my code, appreciate if someone can point out where i am doing wrong -

```
public class QuestionDialog extends DialogFragment
{

     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
          // Get the layout inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
         // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            final View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.ques_dialog,null);
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.ques_dialog, null))

            .setTitle("Title Message!")  
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("GO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {

                          EditText et1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.et1);

                      // here not able to get the data from edit text 

                          String s1 = et1.getText().toString().trim();
                          Log.d("debug","data -"+s1+" and length"+s1.length());

                        .... rest code goes here 

                       })
                     .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {

                            ..rest code goes here

                         }

                       });              

        return builder.create();

     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because of this lines:

```
final View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.ques_dialog,null);
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.ques_dialog, null))
```

You first inflate the *v* `View` and then set as the content of the dialog a **newly inflated view**(so in the end you end up looking for a view which isn't the actual content of the dialog). Use this:

```
final View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.ques_dialog,null);
builder.setView(v);
```